# Two Android apps with different package names using one Facebook app for sharing

Tags: android, android-facebook

When creating app on Facebook it requires Android apps' Google Play Package Name and Main Class Name.
I have com.myapp and com.myapp.pro is that possible to use the same Facebook app for sharing? Or I need to create another one for pro version?

As I see it works for both apps if I specify only "com.myapp". Is there any reason then to specify package name and class?

Comment: any solution you got ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to create another facebook account for another application because in when you cannot install both app in same device.

```
      <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
            android:exported="true" />
```

in device if same facebook id is get then one appliaction cannot be get installed.So it is better to create another facebook app for second app.

Comment: As I understand If i'm sharing only links I don't need a content provider.